# OpenFace giving issues with crontab

Tags: python, bash, cron, torch

I am trying to use openface for face recognition. I am able to run the code properly without using crontab but as soon as i try to run the code using crontab i am getting error as `/usr/bin/env: th: No such file or directory` i searched on the internet and i found that it is having some trouble while finding the path of **`th`** so i have moved all the files using command `cp -R /home/cdh/torch/install/bin/* /usr/bin/th` but still i am getting the same error. Please help as i am stuck in this issue and needed it to be done badly. My workflow.sh file which i am giving my cronjob to run is below.

**workflow.sh :**

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH='/bin/bash'
export PATH='/bin/python'

echo "Model running"
cd /home/cdh/openface-master
/bin/python /xxx/xxx/openface-master/demos/classifier_updated.py
```

As i mentioned earlier if i run only `/bin/python /xxx/xxx/openface-master/demos/classifier_updated.py` i am getting the desired output only if i do using crontab i am getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me the issue with using export inside script. You are replacing the existing path variables to lastly as /bin/python. Please try below:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/bin/python/:/bin/bash
```

Note: /bin/bash should be aleady in the path variable but since you are using updated that here.

Comment: i tried this way now i am getting `/usr/bin/env: th: Permission denied` this error.

Comment: then the issue is with the user you are trying to run the crontab with. Check the user permissions and provide the user sudo access run the script using sudo command.

Comment: I solved that by using `bash -l -c` in front of the python code. Thanks for your help i'll upvote your answer. Please upvote my questiuon if you find it good.